# Does $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:\:}\left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^{n+1}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

This is a geometric series, where $a=(3/4)^2$  and $r=-3/4$, meaning that it converges to $9/28$ right? The answer in my textbook says that it diverges, whereas Symbolab says it converges absolutely. So does it converge or diverge?

Comment: It most definitely converges since it's a geometric series whose ratio has absolute value less than $1$.

Comment: Absolute convergence is a very strong result in analysis. So basically, IF you can show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converges, then you know the sum *without* absolute value $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ WILL converge ALSO. It makes showing convergence of some sums much easier.

Comment: Your textbook probably has a typo.

Answer (score 2):

This is an absolutely convergent series, therefore the series has to converge regardless of the minus signs.

Answer (score 1):

The series can be written as the sum of positive terms and negative terms.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(-3/4)^{i+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(3/4)^{2k}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(3/4)^{2k+1} = a_n - b_n$$

Both $a_n$ and $b_n$ being geometric series are convergent.

Hence, their sum should also be a convergent series. [Proof of convergence of sum of two convergent series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200194/proving-convergence-of-sum-of-two-convergent-series)

Answer (score 1):

If $|x| < 1$ then
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n
=\frac1{1-x}$.

Therefore

$\begin{align}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^{n+1}
&=\left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\frac{9}{16}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^{n}\\
&=\frac{9}{16}\frac1{1-\left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)}\\
&=\frac{9}{16}\frac{4}{4+3}\\
&=\frac{9}{4\cdot 7}\\
&=\frac{9}{28}\\
\end{align}
$

Answer (score 1):

The Leibniz criterion  could be mentioned.

The series is convergent.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test